# No implicit conversion of Fixnum into String, though "to_i" is used

Tags: ruby, string, fixnum

I'm doing a task in "Learn to Program" by Chris Pine. The program asks for a person's favorite number, adds +1, and shows the result. I wrote this:

```
puts 'Hello, what\' your favorite number?'
number = gets.to_i
puts 'Here\' a better bigger favorite number - ' + number + 1
```

And it returned this:

```
Better_number.rb:3:in \'+\': no implicit conversion of Fixnum into String (TypeError)
```

I also tried

```
number = gets.chomp.to_i
```

but that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Your wrong in here `puts 'Here\' a better bigger favorite number - ' + number + 1 ` because  `'Here\' a better bigger favorite number - ' ` is a string and `number` is integer so can not using `+` for string and fixnum

Comment: So what exactly do you want to show?

Comment: I want to show the person's number+ 1. 
Hello, what' your favorite number?
45
Here' a better bigger favorite number  46

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't add a number to a string in ruby. You have to make it a string.

```
puts 'Hello, what\' your favorite number?'
number = gets.to_i
puts 'Here\' a better bigger favorite number - ' + (number + 1).to_s
# or 
bigger_number = number + 1
puts 'Here\' a better bigger favorite number - ' + bigger_number.to_s
# or 
puts "Here's a better bigger favorite number - #{bigger_number}"
```

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I think the term 'casting' might be misleading here.  By calling to_s, a whole new object is created, a string, that is the string representation of the number.

Comment: @KeithBennett: yeah, sorry, old terminology :)

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
puts "Here\' a better bigger favorite number - #{number + 1}"
```

You can not sum string with number.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **`#{"interpolation"}`** to fix your problem.

```
puts 'Hello, what\' your favorite number?'
number = gets.to_i
puts 'Here\' a better bigger favorite number - #{number + 1}'
```